# Differentiable function f has no x in R so that x is root of f and f'. Then no of roots of f in [0,1] is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  be differentiable and assume that there is no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0\ \& \ f'(x)=0$. Show that the set $S=\{x \in [0,1]\ : \ f(x)=0\}$ is finite.

Here is how I tried it.

Say that $S$ is not finite. Then, there is a atkeast countably many $ x_n$ so that $f$ is $0$ and $f'$ is nonzero at those points. i.e. $f $ attains local minima/maxima at those countably many points. Since $ f$ is continuous, local maxima/minimas keeps on exchanging. Can we somehow proceed in this way and get any contradiction on the fact that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: $f'(x)=0$ does not impy that there is a local min/max at $x$

Comment: If there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=0$, then $S=\emptyset$.

Comment: @YuiToCheng There may be $x$ with $f(x)=0\ne f'(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your sequence $x_n$, you can pick a convergent subsequence with limit point $L\in[0,1]$ (for simplicity, let's assume $x_n\to L$). By continuity of $f$, we have $f(L)=0$. Also, $f'(L)=\lim\frac{f(x_n)-f(L)}{x_n-L}=0$.